# How can i fully hide Activity with Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

i stared an activity
as `startActivity(intent);`
and i have a Fragment on it.

```
Fragment fragment = createFragment(list);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

Can i some how hide this Activity with fragment but `onCreateView` on Fragment must work properly and all components on it must be available in a hide ?
i want in "hide mode" set the components of fragment.

Comment: What do you mean by hide exactly? The activity is a container for the fragment; therefore, the fragment would appear inside the activity in the assigned container; therefore, ensure the container is a full size container of the activity. Explain what you are currently seeing and what do you want to see?

Comment: i don't want see anything, but i want to have rights to set in fragments fields.
i hided ActionBar and made activity transparent, but it doesn't work, i see a black or white screen.